# SQL SELECT query returns duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to select some records but instead of 124 I get 992 records with the next query. Can anyone help me please? I get duplicates of the same records and I don't know why.

```sql
SELECT uszc_posts.*, uszc_postmeta.*, uszc_users.*, uszc_utilizatori_acord.*
FROM uszc_posts, uszc_postmeta, uszc_users, uszc_utilizatori_acord
WHERE uszc_posts.ID = uszc_postmeta.post_id
AND uszc_users.ID = uszc_posts.post_author
AND uszc_users.user_email = uszc_utilizatori_acord.email
AND uszc_posts.ID IN (783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 1120, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129, 1130, 1131, 1132, 1133, 1134, 1135, 1136, 1150, 1151, 1152, 1153, 1154, 1156, 1157, 1158, 1159, 1160, 1161, 1162, 1163, 1164, 1165, 1166, 1167, 1168, 1169, 1170, 1171, 1172, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1176, 1177, 1178, 1179, 1309, 1310, 1311, 1312, 1313, 1314, 1315, 1316, 1317, 1318, 1319, 1320, 1321, 1322, 1323, 1324, 1325, 1326, 1327, 1328, 1329, 1330, 1331, 1332, 1333, 1334, 1335, 1336, 1337, 1338, 1339, 1340, 1341, 1342, 1343, 1344, 1345, 1346, 1347, 1348, 1349, 1350, 1351, 1352, 1353, 1354, 1355, 1356, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1360, 1361, 1362, 1363)
ORDER BY `uszc_posts`.`post_date`  ASC
```

I've also tried using `SELECT DISTINCT(post_author)` but I get only 25 results instead of 124.

Comment: did you try `SELECT DISTINCT uszc_posts.*, ...`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, yes I did. Updated my question with what you said just now. I know for sure the query should return 124 records

Comment: You should provide sample data and schema, you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ Without data there is no way we guess why you dont have the rows you want.

Comment: You need to provide us with sample data, output you get, and output you expect to get. Without these we can only guess what may have gone wrong.

Comment: I get the all the columns from those table only they are showed multiple times. It should be 124 rows instead of 992.

Comment: Again without out data we cant help you, sorry :(

Comment: @lonut Out of the 992 records you are getting, pick any 2 that seem to be duplicate. Compare the data for each column and you will find out why there are 2 records instead of one. Adding more columns to the order by clause will help you in getting the duplicates.

Comment: @Adish, What do you mean by that? I don't really understand " Adding more columns to the order by clause will help you in getting the duplicates." I should not use order by?

Comment: If you include more columns to your order by clause, the result set will be more ordered and duplicate rows will come up together

Comment: @Adish. Same result with adding more order by conditions...I want to return those records that contains those ids in the "IN" clause

Comment: Adding more columns to the orderby clause was not meant to return less rows. I just want you to identify 2 rows that seem to be duplicate. Then post the two rows here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really getting duplicates, you are getting very similar rows due to the way you are joining to the `postmeta` table. For example, assume you have one post with ID of `1`, and it has three postmeta values, `1`, `2`, `3`, if you run the following query you will get back 3 rows.

```sql
SELECT p.ID, pm.meta_value FROM posts p, postmeta pm WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id
```

Results:

```
p.ID  pm.meta_value
===================
1     1
1     2
1     3
```

Depending on your desired results, there are different solutions to this problem. If you just want aggregate data for your `posts`, you can `GROUP BY p.ID` to return a single row for each of the posts, however you will lose resolution on your `postmeta` values, and can't guarantee which one will be returned. You could specify a `postmeta` value to further reduce the duplicates, however there may still be duplicate entries for a particular key in this table, thus you would still need a `GROUP BY` if you only want one row per post.

This is how I would write your query

```sql
-- using COUNT(p.Id) will show you how many results were GROUP(ed) BY the p.ID
SELECT COUNT(p.Id) num_results, p.*, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value, u.*, ua.*
FROM uszc_posts p
LEFT JOIN uszc_postmeta pm
    ON pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '?????' -- the key you are interested in
LEFT JOIN uszc_users u
    ON u.ID = p.post_author
LEFT JOIN uszc_utilizatori_acord ua
    ON ua.email = u.user_email
WHERE p.ID IN (783, 784, 785....)
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.post_date ASC
```